# Multiprocessing redis instance -thread_lock error

Tags: python, redis, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I've a large dataframe(million rows) out of which I create more dataframes by filtering according to a particular column. Now, I want to insert the data into redis where I would be performing some heavy calculations. I'm trying to create an instance of redis and trying to paralleize the insertion of data into redis database via multiprocessing. I'm new to multiprocessing and getting an error while inserting the data. I'm not sure whether it can be done or not and why I'm getting the thread_lock error. Can anyone explain and how can I proceed ahead for the solution.

Here is the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
r=redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost',port='6379',db=0)
q=Queue()
p1=Process(target=insertintoRedis,args=(df1,q,r))
p2=Process(target=insertintoRedis,args=(df2,q,r))
p1.start()
p2.start()
p1.join() 
p2.join() 


def insertintoRedis( df, q ,r):
  for row in df.values:
    r.hset(row[-5],row[0],row[-4])
  return
```

I get this error at p1.start():

```
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is that `r`, the instance of `redis.StrictRedis`, cannot be pickled and thus passed as an argument to `insertIntoRedis` and that each process must create its own instance of `redis.StrictRedis`. If you will be invoking `insetintoRedis` many times (unfortunately, your code is *overly* simplified), it might be best instead to use a *process pool* where you would only have to create an instance of `redis.StrictRedis` for each process in the pool, which can be reused repeatedly. This would also make it possible to get a return values back from your worker function `insetintoRedis` (if the reason for passing a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance to this function is for results, you would no longer need this -- but again this cannot be deduced from your lack of code).

Here is the general idea:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue
from functools import partial

def init_pool():
    global r
    r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port='6379', db=0)

# right now limit the pool size to 2 since we only have two tasks:    
q = Queue()
pool = Pool(2, initializer=init_pool)
return_values = pool.map(partial(insertintoRedis, q), [df1, df2])

# note that the order of the arguments has been changed:
def insertintoRedis(q, df):
  for row in df.values:
    r.hset(row[-5],row[0],row[-4])
  return # or return some_value
```

Perhaps `multiprocessing.Pool.imap` would be the more appropriate method to use if you have a very large collection of dataframes and you wish to avoid creating the large list required by `map` and can use instead a generator function or expression.